How to prevent a user from sending an email directly from an object's detail page?
I don't want users to have the ability to click on an email from this Account Contact's object page and have UI pop up to send an email. Ideally this would show as plain text, or a hyperlink that does not have the UI pop up to send an email when clicked.
Can I only do this by changing the field type to text? I'm worried about other areas in the application that this may affect if I do this

We would be better equipped to help if you explained why you have this business requirements. Please see the X-Y Problem for more information.
